# JDA Discord BOT not working after closing Intellij + red error message on discord channel

Tags: java, api, discord, bots

I've created a simple BOT to discord just with a "slash command system". While I'm closing Intellij or turning off my computer, bot going offline. I need to open IntelliJ and open my DiscordBot project (of course build it or run it). Please find my short code below

```
package me.watch2getherdiscord;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDA;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.JDABuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Guild;

import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;

public class Main {

    private static final String TOKEN = "{token}";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws LoginException {

        JDA jda = JDABuilder.createDefault(TOKEN)
                .addEventListeners(new GetRoom())
                .build();

        Guild guild = jda.getGuildById("{my id}");

        if(guild != null){
            guild.upsertCommand("w2g","Let's watch 2gether!").queue();
        }

    }
}
```

```
package me.watch2getherdiscord;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.interaction.command.SlashCommandInteractionEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

public class GetRoom extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onSlashCommandInteraction(@NotNull SlashCommandInteractionEvent event) {

        if(event.getName().equals("w2g")){
            event.getChannel().sendMessage("test").queue();
        }

    }
}
```

Disregarding this case - when i'm typing my command, BOT answering on my question but with that there is red error on my discord server "Application is not responding". Under that it says "Only you can see this - delete this message"

(sorry, not enough point to post image here)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHbV9.png

So to summarize:

1. Why my BOT is stopping every Intellij closure (already answered)
2. After typing my command on Discord channel, I still have this red error like on screenshot.

Thank you,

Comment: Yes, you need to actually run the code for it to respond. If you stop it from running it will also stop responding.

Comment: So basically when I want to close Intellij, click disconnect instead of terminate?

Answer (score 0):

Right now your bot will only be online if your code is running. To keep your coding running I would recommend [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/), which is a free hosting service and works really well. There are plenty of tutorials online explaining how to host your bot there.

As for your second issue, your bot doesn't know when to load the commands. You have it upsert commands during start-up.

There are two ways of adding commands.

1. **A guild command** - This command will be added into Discord instantly! The downside is that it is limited to only a 100 commands and is added per guild.
2. **A global command** - This command will be added throughout Discord. As long as your bot is in a server, that server will get the command. You can add unlimited commands. Downside is it might take up to an hour or maybe even more to add.

So to add commands it is very simple. We will use two events.

**Guild Commands:**

```
@Override
public void onGuildReady(@NotNull GuildReadyEvent event) {
    List<CommandData> commandData = new ArrayList<>();
    commandData.add(Commands.slash("w2g", "A test command"));
    event.getGuild().updateCommands().addCommands(commandData).queue();
}
```

This is a simple command handler for a guild command. Every time you create a new command, just add it here. The steps for creating a global command are nearly identical.

**Global Commands:**

```
@Override
public void onReady(@NotNull ReadyEvent event) {
    List<CommandData> commandData = new ArrayList<>();
    commandData.add(Commands.slash("w2g", "A test command"));
    event.getJDA().updateCommands().addCommands(commandData).queue();
}
```

These two methods are different events. The `onGuildReady()` method fires everytime a guild is ready to accept the commands. The `onReady()` method only fires on **bot** start-up.

These are basic command handlers for you to use. If you are creating a much more advanced bot, I would recommend creating a way for you to easily add commands, unpack the command data and add it to Discord.